# Compare date (string) in PouchDB find

Tags: pouchdb

I have a CouchDB hosted, which has a date (string?) field that has values like "03-Mar-2007". I have an angular app which uses a pouch db to pull data from remote and do stuff.

I need to find records which have the date value less than current date.

I use below code but it does not work.

```
 db.createIndex({
                index: {
                    //fields: ['Pincode', 'subscriberid']
                    fields: ['Pincode', 'IssueDtto']
                }
            })....
```

I use 'find' to search records:

```
var cdate = getFormattedDate($scope.curdate);

function getFormattedDate(date) {
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
            month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
            var day = date.getDate().toString();
            day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
            return day + '-' + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + '-' + year;
        }

 db.find({
    selector: {
    Pincode: { $eq: pin }
    ,IssueDtto: { $lt: cdate }
   }
```

This however does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find/issues/235 might be interesting for you

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before posting this question, but it didn't work.. I just made a workaround..

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the date to a sortable format, such as the ISO format you get from `date.toISOString()`. Dates look like this: `2007-03-01T00:00:00.000Z`, which sorts nicely with string sorting. Then you can also use indexes and use `find`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround, removed the 'date' field selector from db.find, just used only the other selector, got all docs and (manually) filtered rows.

```
angular.forEach(r.docs, function (val) {
 var dt = new Date(val.IssueDtto);
 if (dt < $scope.curdate)
   $scope.todo.push(val);
 });
```